# Carrierwave file uploading not working - Nil value gets saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading

I am trying to upload/save images in the database with carrierwave. But my attachment is not getting persist on the db. only the name field stores in the table.

I was referring to this tutorials : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm

I tried few different ways to change the strong params after thorough research. But nothing worked :(

On the table

```
#<ProjectImage id: 6, name: "Image 3", attachment: nil>
```

ProjectImagesController:

```
def new
    @projectImage = ProjectImage.new
  end


  def projectImage_params
      params.require(:project_image).permit(:name, attachment:[])
        #params.require(:project_image).permit(:project_image_attributes=>['name','attachment'])  ---- no luck
        #params.require(:project_image).permit(:name, :attachment,{}) ------ no luck
  end
```

View

```
<%= form_for ProjectImage.new, html: { multipart: true } do |image| %>

     <h4>   <%= image.label :name %>
            <%= image.text_field :name %>
     </h4>
     <h4>
            <%= image.label :attachment %>
             <%= image.file_field :attachment, multiple: true %>
     </h4>
      <%= image.submit "Save" %>
   <% end %>
```

Parameters

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I+Q==", "project_image"=>{"name"=>"Image 3", "attachment"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000592c4d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160412-7900-1y69rwv.jpg>, @original_filename="jet.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project_image[attachment][]\"; filename=\"jet.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}, "commit"=>"Save"}

    [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000592c4d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/STUART~1.MIN/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160412-7900-1y69rwv.jpg>, @original_filename="jet.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project_image[attachment][]\"; filename=\"jet.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]



class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base 
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader 
end
```

AttachmentUploader class

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
storage :file
  uploader = AttachmentUploader.new
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

    def extension_white_list
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
 end
```

Any help would be admired!
Cheers

Comment: Removing  multiple: true from <%= image.file_field :attachment %> made this work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing multiple: true from <`%= image.file_field :attachment %>` made this work
Cheers